# Binding IDataErrorInfo error in a textblock in application ressource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm setting up a form validation using `IDataErrorInfo`.

For that I have created an error template in the Application resources:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="errorTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
      <Border BorderBrush="OrangeRed" BorderThickness="2">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
      </Border>
      <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding EmailError}" Foreground="Red"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

I store the error in the `EmailError` property of a `RegistrationVM` class, which inherits from `IDataErrorInfo`.

I want to display it, but instead it just spits an error

> Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'EmailError' property not found on 'object' ''ValidationError' (HashCode=10961125)'. BindingExpression:Path=EmailError; DataItem='ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1' (HashCode=13543581); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

The reason, why I wanna use `IDataErrorInfo` is because I wanna have multiple fields with individual validations. If anyone has better idea then feel free to share it.

Comment: the reason i wanna use ```IDataErrorInfo``` is because i wanna have multiple fields with individual validations, if anyone has better idea feel free to share it

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The current DataContext is a ValidationError, not a RegistrationVM. See [Data validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview#data-validation) for how it is supposed to be implemented.

Comment: Rather than relying on index zero as the documentation suggests, I would recommend using current in collection. This copes with an empty collection should your markup ever show up in the UI somehow when there are none. (Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent. I recomend INotifyDataErrorInfo.

Comment: Sorry i just realized the title is misleading, unlike the documentations i found about IDataErrorInfo, I'm not trying to display the error in a Tooltip, but in a TextBlock just underneath the TextBox, I know how to do this with INotifyDataErrorInfo,  but what if i have multiple fields with different validation errors for each ?